# Calling a Python script from a button using Glade Designer

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

How can I call the Ubuntu One authentication python script from a button using Glade?

what I need to do is call a python script such as: $ python u1file.py login

[Adding Ubuntu One Files support to your app](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/ubuntu-one/adding-ubuntu-one-files-support-to-your-app/)

Answer (score 1):

Gtk is a UI toolkit that is meant to be an event-driven framework. So the best approach would be to wait for some event to happen to execute your python code.

On Glade you can add widgets to a GtkWindow (that is also a widget), and widgets do emit what is called signals. Signals are events that indicate that something has happened. This action can be the user clicked on a button, typed some text, resized the window, etc.

A very simple example can be found here [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW5zK.jpg)]

And here is a part I extracted

[image: Panels in Glade]

In the properties section, head to the signals tab having previously seleted some widget on the editor, for example a button.

[image: Glade signals]

As you can see in the image above, every signal has a name and can be binded to a "handler". Inside your code you have to create a function with the same name you choosed as your handle, in this case "on_window_destroy"

Then your code should look similar to this:

```
class TutorialApp(object):       
def __init__(self):
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("tutorial.xml")
        # Here we do the binding
    builder.connect_signals({ "on_window_destroy" : my_custom_handler })
    self.window = builder.get_object("window")
    self.window.show()

def my_custom_handler(self, widget):
    # Excecute whatever python code you want here :D

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TutorialApp()
    gtk.main()
```

**Source**

http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW5zK.jpg)]

Answer (score 1):

Import the script like you would do with any other module/package in Python.

```
import u1file
ui1file.login()
```

See Hernantz answer if you don't know how to connect to a button.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you want? This is basically the equivalent of typing `python scriptname.py` in a terminal.

```
 import os
 os.system("python sriptname.py")
```